# Adding a rowsum column to a large sparse matrix

Tags: python, numpy, scikit-learn, scipy

I have a large sparse matrix X (2 mil rows, 23k cols), and I would like to add a rowsum column on it and return a sparse matrix.

I have tried below

```
np.hstack( (X.toarray(),X.sum(axis=1)) )
```

but it doesn't work well with large sparse matrix.

The thing is, when I call `X.toarray()`, it blows up and terminates python kernel without giving any error message.

Similary I have tried

```
sparse.hstack( X ,sparse.csr_matrix(X.sum(axis=1)))
sparse.csr_matrix(X.sum(axis=1)).ndim    # is 2
X.ndim # 2 as well
```

but it give me below error message:

```
~/miniconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/scipy/sparse/construct.py in bmat(blocks, format, dtype)
    546 
    547     if blocks.ndim != 2:
--> 548         raise ValueError('blocks must be 2-D')
    549 
    550     M,N = blocks.shape

ValueError: blocks must be 2-D
```

Is there any way to work around this problem?

Comment: The linked answer says nothing about using `np.hstack`!  `toarray` often fails because the resulting array is too large for your memory.  There's also `sparse.vstack`.

Comment: @hpaulj Somehow I got the wrong link, I removed it.

Comment: Review the docs for `sparse.stack`.  First arg is supposed to be list or tuple.  My answer in your old link is still right.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
In [93]: from scipy import sparse                                                              
In [94]: M = sparse.random(5,7, .2, 'csr')                                                     
In [95]: M                                                                                     
Out[95]: 
<5x7 sparse matrix of type '<class 'numpy.float64'>'
    with 7 stored elements in Compressed Sparse Row format>
```

One sum is a (n,1) `np.matrix`:

```
In [96]: M.sum(axis=1)                                                                         
Out[96]: 
matrix([[0.92949904],
        [1.068337  ],
        [0.10927561],
        [0.        ],
        [0.68352182]])
```

The other a (1,n) matrix:

```
In [97]: M.sum(axis=0)                                                                         
Out[97]: 
matrix([[0.        , 0.90221854, 0.42335774, 1.35578158, 0.        ,
         0.        , 0.10927561]])
```

add the column to the matrix (note the argument details):

```
In [98]: sparse.hstack((M, M.sum(axis=1)))                                                     
Out[98]: 
<5x8 sparse matrix of type '<class 'numpy.float64'>'
    with 11 stored elements in COOrdinate format>
```

add the row matrix:

```
In [99]: sparse.vstack((M, M.sum(axis=0)))                                                     
Out[99]: 
<6x7 sparse matrix of type '<class 'numpy.float64'>'
    with 11 stored elements in COOrdinate format>
```

Comment: To make my answer completely obsolete you should demonstrate that this also works with large arrays. ;-)  `sparse.random` doesn't, actually, but feel free to borrow my workaround.

Answer (score 1):

One potential workaround could be using matrix multiplication like so.

First a small example to see what is going on. `x` is a helper matrix, `yy` would correspond to your data:

```
>>> K,N,D = 5,10,3
>>> 
>>> x = sparse.csc_matrix((np.ones(2*K),np.r_[np.arange(K),np.arange(K)],np.r_[np.arange(K+1),2*K]),(K,K+1))
>>> 
>>> x.A
array([[1., 0., 0., 0., 0., 1.],
       [0., 1., 0., 0., 0., 1.],
       [0., 0., 1., 0., 0., 1.],
       [0., 0., 0., 1., 0., 1.],
       [0., 0., 0., 0., 1., 1.]])
>>> 
>>> y = np.random.randint(0,N,(D,K))
>>> y.sort(0)
>>> yy = sparse.csc_matrix((np.ones(D*K),y.ravel(),np.arange(K+1)*D),(N,K))
>>> 
>>> yy.A
array([[1., 0., 0., 0., 0.],
       [2., 1., 0., 0., 0.],
       [0., 1., 0., 0., 0.],
       [0., 1., 1., 1., 0.],
       [0., 0., 0., 0., 0.],
       [0., 0., 0., 0., 1.],
       [0., 0., 0., 0., 0.],
       [0., 0., 2., 1., 0.],
       [0., 0., 0., 1., 1.],
       [0., 0., 0., 0., 1.]])
>>> 
>>> (yy@x).A
array([[1., 0., 0., 0., 0., 1.],
       [2., 1., 0., 0., 0., 3.],
       [0., 1., 0., 0., 0., 1.],
       [0., 1., 1., 1., 0., 3.],
       [0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.],
       [0., 0., 0., 0., 1., 1.],
       [0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.],
       [0., 0., 2., 1., 0., 3.],
       [0., 0., 0., 1., 1., 2.],
       [0., 0., 0., 0., 1., 1.]])
```

And a larger example to show it scales:

```
>>> K,N,D = 23_000,2_000_000,100
>>> 
>>> x = sparse.csc_matrix((np.ones(2*K),np.r_[np.arange(K),np.arange(K)],np.r_[np.arange(K+1),2*K]),(K,K+1))
>>> x
<23000x23001 sparse matrix of type '<class 'numpy.float64'>'
        with 46000 stored elements in Compressed Sparse Column format>
>>> 
>>> y = np.random.randint(0,N,(D,K))
>>> y.sort(0)
>>> yy = sparse.csc_matrix((np.ones(D*K),y.ravel(),np.arange(K+1)*D),(N,K))
>>> yy
<2000000x23000 sparse matrix of type '<class 'numpy.float64'>'
        with 2300000 stored elements in Compressed Sparse Column format>
>>> 
>>> yy@x
<2000000x23001 sparse matrix of type '<class 'numpy.float64'>'
        with 3667102 stored elements in Compressed Sparse Column format>
```

Comment: The `X.sum(axis=1)` method uses `yy@x[:,-1]` - that is a matrix multiply with a column of ones.  Actually it uses a np.matrix(np.ones((1,n)))` so the result is also `np.matrix`.   Since `hstack` combines the `coo` attributes of the element arrays to make a new `coo`, your all-in-one multiplication might well be faster.